# How to call tests from another test?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, testing, jar

How can I call tests from another test?

I have a class in the jar that I have added as dependency into my project:

```
public class Tests{

private MockMvc mockMvc;


@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {
.....
mockMvc.perform(get(myRequest)
        .content(dataFromDB)
.......
    }
}
@Test
public void test2() throws Exception {
.....
mockMvc.perform(get(myRequest)
        .content(dataFromDB)
.......
    }
}
.......
```

And in my project I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
public class MyTests {
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
   CALL SOMEHOW TESTS FROM THE JAR HERE
}
```

I want those tests from the jar to test my project's database (for example: *dataFromDB* should be some data from the project where this dependency has been added).

I have already added this jar and I can call class Tests inside my project,so I have access to it. I am just not sure how to run those tests inside it.

What should I change so it works well? Thanks

Updated:

*I want all tests from the jar to call at the same time, not individually.

*I want to give jar access to my db, so it can get all needed testing data in the db table of my project.

Answer (score 1):

From what is see, you have 2 sets of environment, and 1 set of tests.

So one way to solve this is that you make the environment passable, the mockmvc, the dataFromDb, etc, so that the tests can execute independently of the environment.

I would suggest having the test methods in another class, like this very simplified example for easy reading:

```
class MyTestMethods {
  void test1(TestEnv env, Req myRequest) {
    env.getMockMvc()
        .perform(env.get(myRequest)
            .content(env.getDataFromDB());
    // assertions here
  }
}

class OldTestInJar {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    new MyTestMethods().test1(myEnv, myReq);
  }
}

class MyNewTest {
  @Test
  public void test1() {
    new MyTestMethods().test1(myNewEnv, myNewReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont want in my project to call each test from the jar individually. I want to call all of them at the same time. Is that possible?

Ok, so I can send my WebApplicationContext like env, right? 
But I dont want to send each request individually. I want to give jar access to my db, where it can find all requests and needed data in the db table. For example in jar I would like to be able to get data like this:
 dataIneed = repo.get("somethingIneed");
and then 
....
 .content(dataIneed)
...

Comment: This is a good example of using multiple implementations of environment. Using dependency injection would be a good use case if you're using something like spring. Just inject the correct environment, and then we just need to run the OldTestInJar with the new environment. No need for NewTestClass to run the old test.